# Floating point numbers - no arithmetic operations and precision errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

Can I ever run into any floating number precision errors if I don't perform any arithmetic operations on the floats? The only operations I do with numbers in my program are limited to the following:

1. Getting numbers as strings from a web service and converting them to floats using `parseFloat()`
2. Comparing resulting floats using `<=` `<` `==` `>` `>=`

Example:

```js
const input = ['1000.69', '1001.04' /*, ... */]
const x = parseFloat(input[0])
const y = parseFloat(input[1])
console.log(x < y)
console.log(x > y)
console.log(x == y)
```

As for `parseFloat()` implemetation, I'm using latest Node.js.

The source of floats is prices in USD as strings, always two decimals.

Comment: I don't know, but testing for equality can be an issue

Comment: @DominikMatis if there are any arithmetic operations, yes. Otherwise, nope.

Comment: Doesn't it depend on the implementation of `parseFloat`?

Comment: according to the documentation- `parseFloat` converts `BigInt` syntax to Numbers, losing precision.

Answer (score 2):

As long as the source of your floats is reliable, your checks are safe, yes.
I'd still round them to an acceptable decimal number after the parsing, just to be 100% safe.

[As the MDN docs show in one of their examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)

```js
// these all return 3.14
parseFloat(3.14);
parseFloat('3.14');
parseFloat('  3.14  ');
parseFloat('314e-2');
parseFloat('0.0314E+2');
parseFloat('3.14some non-digit characters');
parseFloat({ toString: function() { return "3.14" } });

//and of course
parseFloat('3.140000000') === 3.14
```

Comment: As I'm lacking some info it's hard to make a call here. I always round my floats to two decimal places whenever I'm not requiring precision.

Answer (score 1):

The `parseFloat` operation converts a string into it's [number value](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#number-value). The spec says:

> In this specification, the phrase “the Number value for x” where x represents an exact real mathematical quantity (which might even be an irrational number such as π) means a Number value chosen in the following manner. Consider the set of all finite values of the Number type, with -0 removed and with two additional values added to it that are not representable in the Number type, namely 2ℝ1024ℝ (which is +1ℝ × 2ℝ53ℝ × 2ℝ971ℝ) and -2ℝ1024ℝ (which is -1ℝ × 2ℝ53ℝ × 2ℝ971ℝ). **Choose the member of this set that is closest in value to x.**

That reads as if two same strings are always converted to the same closest number. Except for NaN, [two same numbers are equal.](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-samevaluenonnumeric)

> **6.1.6.1.13 Number::equal ( x, y )**
>
> If x is NaN, return false.
>
> If y is NaN, return false.
>
> If x is **the same Number value** as y, return true.
>
> If x is +0 and y is -0, return true.
>
> If x is -0 and y is +0, return true.
>
> Return false.

<sub>emphasis mine</sub>